# Akka actor - sender points to dead letters

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, actor

consider the following example:

```
case class Payload(message: String, async: Boolean)

class EchoActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Payload(message, async) =>
      if (async) Future {
        println(s"from: $sender")
        sender ! message
      } else {
        println(s"from: $sender")
        sender ! message
      }
  }
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val system = ActorSystem("demo")
  val echo = system.actorOf(Props[EchoActor])
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)

  (echo ? Payload("Hello", async = false)).mapTo[String].foreach(println(_))
  (echo ? Payload("Async Hello", async = true)).mapTo[String].foreach(println(_))

  StdIn.readLine()
  system.terminate()
}
```

console output:

```
from: Actor[akka://demo/temp/$a]
Hello
from: Actor[akka://demo/deadLetters]
[INFO] [04/13/2017 19:56:58.516] [demo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://demo/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://demo/user/$a#2112869650] to Actor[akka://demo/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

i.e. the sender points to `deadLetters` when accessing it from another thread.

**What is the reason behind that?**
is it a bug?

although, we can hold a reference to the actual sender to make it work:

```
if (async) {
  val currentSender = sender()
  Future {
    println(s"from: $currentSender")
    currentSender ! message
  }
}
```

but... isn't there some better approach?

Comment: That's actually a correct approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a documented behavior -

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/actors.html#Send_messages

Using `Future` means invoking an anonymous function which is not an instance of the `Actor` class, therefor your `sender()` ref is mapped to the `deadLetters` mailbox

Answer (score 2):

The better approach is the `pipe` pattern.

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

class EchoActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Payload(message, async) =>
      if (async) {
        Future {
          message
        }.pipeTo(sender) 
      } else {
        sender ! message
      }
  }
}
```

The issue is that `sender` is a function and its value is only valid if called *on the same thread* that is processing the incoming message.  When you call `sender` within a future, it's being called from another thread and at another point in time, notably after the actor's receive function has already returned.

`pipeTo` captures the value of the current sender on the same thread as the actor and before the receive function has returned.  This is effectively the same as your approach with the `currentSender` value.

Comment: Btw. your code example still accesses `sender` asynchronously inside the `println`. A better solution would be to put it into a `val` before the `Future` block and refer to that inside the `Future` block.